# Convert XLS to CSV - R (Tried Rio Package)

Tags: r, csv, xls, r-rio

I have a list of files in a directory which I'm trying to convert to csv, had tried rio package and solutions as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826200/dynamically-converting-a-list-of-excel-files-to-csv-files-in-r)

The output is list of empty CSV files with no content. It could be because the first 8 rows of the xls files have an image and few emtpy lines with couple couple of cells filled with text.

Is there any way I could skip those first 8 lines in all of xls files before converting.

[image: Image of Input File. Couldn't add it as table since there is a picture embedded in first couple of rows of the xls files]

Tried exploring options from openxlsx or readxls packages, any suggestions or guidance will be helpful.

Please do not mark as duplicate since I have a different problem than the one that was already answered

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with rio, but almost all packages that read in Excel files have some argument that allows you to skip several rows. It might be called something like `startRow` or `skip`.

Comment: You should be able to do `rio::convert("file.xls", "file.csv", in_opts(skip = 8))`.

Comment: Sorry, that should actually be `rio::convert("file.xls", "file.csv", in_opts = list(skip = 8))`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I get Error: ncol(x) > 0L is not TRUE

Comment: Is one of your spreadsheets empty?

Comment: @Thomas,  all spreadsheets contain data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was not able to do it with rio to convert, I read it as xls and wrote it back as csv using below code. Testing worked fine, Hope it works without glitch in implementation.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = '*.xls')    

y=NULL

for(i in files ) {
  x <- read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, header=TRUE, startRow=9)
  y= rbind(y,x)
}

dt <- Sys.Date()
fn<- paste("path/",dt,".csv",sep="")
write.csv(y,fn,row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the following will work. At least it does for my own mock-up of an excel file with a picture in the top

```
library("readxl")  # To read xlsx
library("readr")   # Fast csv write

indata <- read_excel("~/cowexcel.xlsx", skip=8)
write_csv(indata, path="cow.csv")
```

If you are running this for several files then combine it into a function. Note that the function below does no checking and might overwrite existing csv files

```
convert_excel_to_csv <- function(name) {
    indata <- read_excel(name, skip=8)    
    write_csv(indata, path=paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(name), ".csv"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks  @ekstroem , I was able to do it using xlsx package